# Replace string with same named variable

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace, templating

I wrote some days ago a simple thing to fallback to an placeholder image if the desired image can't loaded. It allows the user to use 2 *placeholders* to to define the image size:

That's the [thing I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17352656/1250044):

```
;(window.jQuery || window.Zepto).fn.fallback = function (url) {
    return this.one('error', function () {
        this.src = (url|| 'http://lorempixel.com/$w/$h')
        .replace('$w', this.width).replace('$h', this.height);
    });
};
```

I'm asking me now, if it is possible to replace `.replace('$w', this.width).replace('$h', this.height);` with an shorter but equal `regex` to replace all `$*` (dollar + first-char) with an assigned value from any object?

Something like this:

```
'$f is not equal to $b'.replace(/magicregex/, {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
});
```

So that we can use all `properties` from the `image-object`, e.g. `image.width`, `image.src`, `image.width`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you use a function as the replacement. Like:

```
"$w/$h".replace(/\$[wh]/g, function(m){ return m == "$w" ? width : height; });
```

You could also do away with the comparison like this:

```
"$w/$h".replace(/\$(?:(w)|h)/g, function(m, w){ return w ? width : height; });
```

If you want to look up a value in a hash you could use:

```
"$w/$h".replace(/\$(\w+)/g, function(m, name){ return hash[name]; });
```

Comment: Mhh, this makes it not more dynamically. It limits the replacments to `$w` and `$h` ;) I've updated my question...

Comment: @yckart, the function can obviously do anything you want. I'll add an example.

Comment: Okay, I'll remove it again :)

Comment: Another thing, is it somehow possible to catch something like `$f` but get all things from the `object` which starts with `f`? So we match `$f` but catch `obj.foo` instead of `obj.f`?